# DomSanitizer DI failed in jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-dom-sanitizer

I am trying to test a simple component with jasmine that have the constructor below

```
constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
```

In my test, i have a testBed like

```
describe("Component: myComponent", () => {
    let component: myComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<myComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule],
            declarations: [myComponent],
        }).compileComponents().then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(myComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
    }));
});
```

I am getting the error

> Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for myComponent

I have tried everything. I followed the suggestion on the question here [Test pipe with dependencies on services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47514436/test-pipe-with-dependencies-on-services) and imported browserModule instead of CommonModule all to no avail. Please how do i inject this dependency ? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just importing the dependency below in my `tests.ts` fixed the issue for me.

```
import "core-js/es7/reflect";
```

Thanks to Odolha from the thread here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19417